# How can i align the Text as Center in TextBlock in WinRT?

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

I have set the VerticalContentAlignment, HorizontalContentAlignment and TextAlignment as Center as per the below code but the text is not aligned center in the TextBox.

```
<TextBox Text="Data" Width="200" Height="50" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"/>
```

How can i achieve this without padding?

Comment: Could you please any one help me

Answer (score 5):

The question title says `TextBlock` but the code show a `TextBox`, so try swapping the `TextBox` for a `TextBlock`, then set the `TextAlignment` property to "Center" (see below):

```
<TextBlock TextAlignment="Center">Data</TextBlock>
```

Hope that helps you.